# Jordan normal form for compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

This question should be standard, but I didn't find it in the books.
For a compact operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$, we know that every spectral value $\ne 0$ is an eigenvalue, that each generalised eigenspace
$$
H(\lambda)=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\ker(T-\lambda)^n, \ \ \ \lambda\ne 0
$$
is finite dimensional and that the eigenvalues can only accumulate at zero.
Is it true that
$\bigoplus _{\lambda\in\mathbb C}H(\lambda)$ is dense in $H$?
Here $\lambda=0$ is included in which case the gerenalised eigenspace may be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Have a look at the forgotten classic by Dunford and Schwartz "*Linear Operators. Part I: General Theory*"  Sec VII.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Consider the Volterra operator $V: L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0,1)$ which is given by $(Vf)(x) = \int_0^x f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$.
This operator is compact and does not have any eigenvalues, so every generalized eigenspace is $\{0\}$.

Comment: You probably want to mention that it is a compact operator.